# How to Use Jstl `<fmt>` tag inside form `action` tag

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I want to insert form action using JSTL `fmt` tag as show below

```
    <form:form name="signupForm" modelAttribute="signupForm"
    action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/<fmt:message key="signuppage.form.signupForm.action.signup"></fmt:message>'
    method="POST">
```

But it is not resolved correctly. Looking at page source it comes as this:

```
<form id="signupForm" name="signupForm" action="/SpringWebTesting/&lt;fmt:message key=&quot;signuppage.form.signupForm.action.signup&quot;&gt;&lt;/fmt:message&gt;" method="POST">
```

How to use it properly?

Comment: Why would the action be internationalized? What are you trying to achieve here? The answer is to use the `var` attribute to store the message in a variable, and then use the variable in the action attribute, but this looks like something you should really not do.

Comment: @JBNizet I wanted to set action's value from a properties file. so in future, I can change it without touching the code. do you think it is a bad practice ?and also, should its value be hardcoded in the form?

Comment: fmt tags are not used to get data from a properties file. They're used for internationalization. The fact that the i18n message keys are stored in a properties file shouldn't make you use i18n tags for non-i18n-related stuff. And yes, I think it's a bad practice. If the action changes, then the Spring controller code changes, so you will have to change code and redeploy anyway. And the bundle is part of the code anyway (just not Java/JSP code, but still code). This will only make code harder to read, and won't provide any significant advantage.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, very helpful. Can you look at one my other question that is still unanswered?. It is related to Spring MVC test framework.